# Need help adding array to a tableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm having trouble adding cells with different content to my app. I know (or think) this needs to be done using an array, but I'm new to xcode and objective-c so I'm not exactly sure how to do this. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Here is a copy of my current code:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
 */

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100;
}
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.imageViews.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"captainaq_4.jpg"];
    cell.firstLabel.text = @"name ";
    cell.secondLabel.text = @"second name";
    cell.thirdLabel.text = @"third name";
    cell.thirdLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /*
    <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
    */
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

First, note that cellForRowAtIndexPath is being called multiple times-- once for each cell.  I think your best option would be to declare an array, and populate it with the objects you want displayed, as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *days[] = {@"Mon", @"Tues", @"Wed", @"Thurs", @"Fri", @"Sat", @"Sun"};
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
[[cell textLabel] setText:days[indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}
```

Or populate the array somewhere else, if you need to manipulate the objects within it.  In that case (assuming your array is populated with strings), your call to setText would look like:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

It also appears you want to have a header with an image in it.  In that case, use:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  //create your UIImageView and add your image
   return yourImageView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok... as far as I have seen , I dont think the following is valid.

```
cell.imageViews.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"captainaq_4.jpg"];
cell.firstLabel.text = @"name ";
cell.secondLabel.text = @"second name";
cell.thirdLabel.text = @"third name";
cell.thirdLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Correct me if I am wrong...

As far as I understood your question, what you got to do is that create labels and add them either programmatically or through Interface Builder ( whichever is easier for you) so that you can display whatever contents you want in the cell...

Here is an example of what you can do..

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator; // adding indicator to the rows

}

// Configure the cell...

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"John Doe";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"DEPT";
        //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"meeting_color.png"];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Mary Smith";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"DEPT";
        //cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"call_color.png"];
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Bob Wong";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"DEPT";
        //cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar_color.png"];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

return cell;
}
```

Again that is a very simple way you can add content to a tableview...

Answer (score 0):

You can create several different UITableViewCell or your own custom cell class and add it into array and display it later under:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

With this, you can have several distinct custom cell (What I mean distinct is totally different cell, such as first cell with image while the other doesn't have image).

While the other alternative is to do it inside the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

as shown by using switch case. Either ways, it's about preference.

I suggest you to learn more about the basic use of classes, such as NSArray, NSMutableArray, and writing Objective-C language first. While it doesn't help much with learning developing app, it will speed up the learning curve during the real implementation of building program in Cocoa environment.